# how can I resolve "JavaScript heap out of memory"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, memory-leaks, jestjs

When I run "yarn test **tests**/screens/Home/Home.js",
I encountered "javascript memory leak" error.
and this file is created. 
File name is "report.20191007.162344.626.0.001.json"

What Can I Do?

```
{
  "header": {
    "event": "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory",
    "trigger": "FatalError",
    "filename": "report.20191007.162344.626.0.001.json",
    "dumpEventTime": "2019-10-07T16:23:44Z",
    "dumpEventTimeStamp": "1570433024575",
    "processId": 626,
    "commandLine": [
      "/usr/local/bin/node",
      "/my app path~/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "__tests__/screens/Home/Home.test.js"
    ],
    "nodejsVersion": "v12.5.0",
    "wordSize": 64,
    "arch": "x64",
    "platform": "darwin",
    "componentVersions": {
      "node": "12.5.0",
      "v8": "7.5.288.22-node.14",
      "uv": "1.29.1",
      "zlib": "1.2.11",
      "brotli": "1.0.7",
      "ares": "1.15.0",
      "modules": "72",
      "nghttp2": "1.38.0",
      "napi": "4",
      "llhttp": "1.1.4",
      "http_parser": "2.8.0",
      "openssl": "1.1.1c",
      "cldr": "35.1",
      "icu": "64.2",
      "tz": "2019a",
      "unicode": "12.1"
    },
}
```

Home.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Home from '../../../src/screens/Home/Home';
import configureStore from '../../../src/store/configureStore'
const store = configureStore();

test('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<Home store={store} />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: This code is part of created file.

Comment: There seems to be a memory issue in `Home.test.js`. Maybe it's allocating too much memory or maybe there's an infinite loop somewhere

Comment: @apokryfos 
running the test on another file with the same code works fine.

Comment: what does a `java memory leak` have to do with javascript?

Comment: you've shown the code that tests whatever, but you haven't shown the code that is being tested - the problem is probably with the code being tested, not the test code itself

Comment: is there any chance your store contains a circular reference?